# How to run a Jar file in soapui

Tags: java, soapui

I have a question regarding running a jar file in soapui. The project its self is a spring boot application, so when I run the application, I will be able to send an xml request from soapui in which the java application will read it, do some transformation and return a response.

I've done a bit of research on this, but most of these answers appear to be incomplete, some missing out import statements. I was hoping someone could help me identify how to do this?

This is what I've found online:

```
def command = "java -jar UpdateAppIdXMLRequest.jar file.xml"
def process = command.execute()
process.waitFor()
def output = process.in.text
log.info output
```

I don't understand what the purpose of "file.xml" is.

Please help

This is what I am currently trying to execute:

```
import example.example.Application

def command="java -jar myjarFile"
def process = command.execute()
process.waitFor()
def output = process.in.text
log.info output
```

Comment: file.xml is argument to main method

Comment: Right I understand. At the moment, I'm having an issue with my import statement. It saying it can't resolve the class.. I've made an edit, you can take a look